# How to change value of variable passed as an argument in python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to code a little game about planets in pygame. I was trying to implement a way to stop the movement of the planets by stoping them from updating their position if a global variable `paused` was set to true.

This is what the code for the main looks like:

```
import pygame, events
from planet import *

pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()

font = pygame.font.SysFont('Corbel', 50, True)

size = pygame.display.Info()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((size.current_w, size.current_h), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
bg = (5, 0, 10)

sun = Planet(0, 0, 10000, 200, (200, 230, 70), (0, 0))

idle_planets = [sun]
planets = []
prev = []

paused = False

while True:
    mousePos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        events.onQuit(event)
        events.keyDown(event, idle_planets, paused)
        events.mousePressed(event, mousePos, prev, idle_planets)

    window.fill(bg)
    
    planetSpawn(window, prev, planets, mousePos)

    planetLogic(planets, idle_planets, window, paused)

    planetCount = font.render(str(len(planets)), True, (255, 255, 255))
    window.blit(planetCount, (100, 100))

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```

The part of the code that handles the events is in another file and imported as events (just to organize it a little bit), and the part of the function `keyDown()` that is supposed to change the variable paused looks like this:

```
if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
    paused = not paused
```

Note that this function does more than this, it checks for `K_BACKSPACE` and `K_ESCAPE` and does different things at the same time, so returning a value is something I'm trying to avoid and doesn't work anyways (tried it).

Also, the part of the code that prevents the planets from moving when `paused = True` looks like this (simplified):

```
def planetlogic(planetList, idlePlanetList, root, paused):
    for planet in planetList:
        planet.draw(root)
        if paused:
            continue
        
        planet.update()

        #rest of the function
```

Before I moved the event checks to another file everything worked fine. The issue now is that the variable `paused` doesn't change, though the rest of the code related to the key events works just fine.

I did some testing and discovered this:

```
def invert(b):
    b = not b

myVar = False
invert(myVar)
print(myVar)
```

The code above will not change the value of `myVar` which doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

So, is there a way I can invert the variable `paused` without having to explicitly write the code inside the function `keyDown()` inside the gameloop?

Let me know if I made any spelling or grammar mistakes since english is my second language. And also let me know if my code sucks, which is pretty likely.

Comment: Python has no concept of in-out parameters. You have to `return` the new value from the function. Alternatively create a class with an `paused` attribute and an `invert` method.

Answer (score 0):

just return the inverted value from the method.
in your code b is being updated inside method only.

```
def invert(b):
    return not b

myVar = False
myVar = invert(myVar)
print(myVar)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me introduce it with your example:

```py
def invert(b):
    b = not b

myVar = False
invert(myVar)
print(myVar)
```

What is actually happening here?

Any value that you pass to the "invert" function as a parameter will be a new variable inside it and has its own memory address.

So in this case, you can do something like this:

```py
def invert(b):
    return not b

myVar = False
print("My var before inverting:", myVar)
myVar = invert(myVar) # line 6
print("My var after inverting:", myVar)
```

Can you see the changes?

We are returning a value from the invert function and reassigning the myVar variable with it.

I suggest you read more about scopes or watch this tutorial.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QVdf0LgmICw&t=918s

Comment: "Any value that you pass to the "invert" function as a parameter will be a new variable inside it and has its own memory address." This is actually pretty useful. I managed to solve it, but as I said in the post, it didn't work when using this method. I had to write code so that the function returned true and then, using an if statment, invert the value of my variable. Maybe in another context it would have worked.